# Quicksort implementation in C language

Tags: c, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in c language but the sorting is not happening as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quickSort(int arr[], int length);
void qSrtRec(int arr[], int low, int high);
void swap(int* x, int* y);
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high);

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 5,3,7,0,1,4,8,9,6,2 }; // test array

    quickSort(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void swap(int* x, int* y) {
    *x += *y;
    *y = *x - *y;
    *x -= *y;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int length) {
    qSrtRec(arr, 0, length - 1);
}

void qSrtRec(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
        qSrtRec(arr, low, pivot - 1);
        qSrtRec(arr, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    int i = low, pivotValue = arr[high];

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
        if (arr[j] <= pivotValue) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            i++;
        }

    swap(&arr[high], &arr[i]);

    return i;
}
```

Compared to the test array i am getting the output as 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0. Swap fuction works correctly but i am not sure about the partition function.

Comment: Swap function doesn't work if `i == j`

Comment: How about using a temporary variable to swap the values instead?

Comment: @Haris exclusive or has the same issue in the case of aliasing.

Comment: @mousetail answers to the answers section please ;-)

Comment: @deto: Use a better `swap()` and report if problem remains: `void swap(int* x, int* y) { int t = *y; *y = *x; *x = t; }`

Comment: @mousetail that's new to me, thank you. :)

Comment: @deto, Curious, what text or who suggested `*x += *y; *y = *x - *y; *x -= *y;`?  It certainly fails to swap when `x == y` and risks _undefined behavior_ with `int` overflow with other test values.

Comment: Just as a side note: `pivotValue = arr[high]` is inefficient if the array already *is* sorted. There are better approaches for, e.g. selecting the median of `arr[low]`, `arr[mid]`, `arr[high]` as proposed by [Sedgewick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot).

Comment: Note, too, that actually `int` is not the right type for specifying array sizes (and usually indices as well, unless for specific pointer arithmetic) – for this purpose `size_t` (from `<stddef.h>` has been designed...

Comment: @mousetail swap function still works if i == j.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was trying to save memory by using only 2 variables. However, I am curious as to why it does not work. Although, when testing the function I did not use the array but individual int x and y.

Comment: @deto,  "curious as to why it does not work."  When `x == y`, `*x += *y;` doubles `*x`.  `*y = *x - *y;` is the same as `*y = *x - *x;`, so now `*x == 0` as well as `*y == 0` since `x==y`.  Tip: "trying to save memory by using only 2 variables. (instead of 3)" is a micro-optimization.  Only useful if you are better than the compiler (doubtful).  Instead focus on larger issues.  Note : you still avoided answering "what text or who suggested ..".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It was not a suggestion, I tried it on my own. I tested the swap function giving `int a` and `int b` the same values but the value did not go to 0, is it possible it is behaving that way because it is not an individual int but an array of int?

Comment: Problem is when both pointers are to same location. In your code you are swapping same location multiple times. Add `printf `to show values of `i` and `j` to see it.

Comment: @tymmej even if the value stored at the separate location is the same but the location is different so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I also checked the swap function with an array using different and same values of an array length of 2. It works just fine. Still unclear why is it behaving the way it is.

Comment: `int main() {`

    `int a[] = { 5, 5 };`
    `printf("0 = %d, 1 = %d\n", a[0], a[1]);`
    `swap(&a[0], &a[1]);`
    `printf("0 = %d, 1 = %d\n", a[0], a[1]);`
    `return 0;`
`}`
`void swap(int* x, int* y) {`

    `*x = *x + *y;`
    `*y = *x - *y;`
    `*x = *x - *y;`
`}`

This is the test case I was using.

Comment: @deto You don't understand what people are telling you.  The problem doesn't occur when `*x == *y` (obviously).  It occurs when `x == y`, i.e., when there's a *single* integer variable, and both pointers point to it.  Take the time to understand why this can't possibly work.  Also, look at the answer that was posted.  That will fix the problem.

Comment: @deto Try to understand.  If you call `swap(&arr[i], &arr[j])`, and `i == j`, then there is a single integer location involved.  So let's say `a[i]` is `5`.  You call `swap`.  It sets this to `10`.  Then it  subtracts it from itself, giving it the value `0`.  Then it subtracts it from itself again, with the final value being `0`.  That is your bug.  It should be `5`.  Remember, `i == j` for the bug to appear.  A *single* pointer value, passed twice.  Not two pointers that point to integers with the same value.  One pointer, passed twice.

Comment: @deto The reason that case is different it because when you assign to `*x`, `*y` changes as well.  Look:  If `x == y`, then we can replace `y` with `x` in this case, making it clearer (since in this case there's only one pointer value).  First it does `*x += *x`, doubling it.  Then it does `*x = *x - *x`, setting it to zero,  Then it does `*x -= *x`, and it stays zero.  Get a pencil and paper and walk through it.  This is brain-dead simple.

Comment: @deto Note that another way to fix this is to add `if (x == y) return;` to the top of your `swap` function.  That would intercept the problem case.  Then it would work (assuming your integer addition doesn't overflow).  You're still better off assigning to a temporary variable, but this would circumvent the specific case that's causing your function to fail.

Answer (score 6):

The `Swap` function is the problem. It will work if you replace it with:

```
void swap(int* x, int* y) {
    int t = *y;
    *y = *x;
    *x = t;
}
```

The program now outputs `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,`

Comment: could you please explain what was wrong with my approach, since I am accessing the memory of the pointer and not the address it should work?

Comment: The functions breaks when the two pointers passed in are equal, which happens several times during execution. In this scenario `*x += *y;` is over-writing `*y` when you don't want this so the next line `*y = *x - *y;` is going to assign `0`.